# What strings can Dojo 1.7 dojo/on accept for type parameter?

Tags: javascript, dojo

What strings can dojo/on accept for the type parameter.

http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/on

Describes "**This is the name of the event type to be dispatched (like select). This event may be a standard event (like click) or a custom event (like finished).**" but is there a list somewhere of the types of things I can put in here? Does it have the same capacity to filter the events to dispatch on as if I were using dojo/query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just browsed to the Dojo 1.8 API docs, and if you select a specific Dijit you can see the events in an *Event Summary* section. For example [`dijit/Tree`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dijit/Tree):

- onBlur() Called when the widget stops being "active" because focus moved to something outside of it, or the user clicked somewhere outside of it, or the widget was hidden.
- onClick(item, node, evt) Callback when a tree node is clicked
- onClose(item, node) Callback when a node is closed
- onDblClick(item, node, evt) Callback when a tree node is double-clicked
- ...

And [`dojox/treemap/TreeMap`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dojox/treemap/TreeMap)

- onBlur() Called when the widget stops being "active" because focus moved to something outside of it, or the user clicked somewhere outside of it, or the widget was hidden.
- onChange() Called when the selection changed.
- onFocus() Called when the widget becomes "active" because it or a widget inside of it either has focus, or has recently been clicked.
- onItemRollOut() Called when an item renderer has been rolled out.
- onItemRollOver() Called when an item renderer has been hovered.
- onRendererUpdated() Called when a renderer has been updated.

I'm not sure if there is a (easy) way of aggregating all the events across all the components. So might just be a case of reading the docs for the component you are interested in.

Comment: @PaulGrimeSo that's super helpful. Thank you. What I mean though is you've got a string that can be a powerful filtering selector. So you can say something like "ol[class=foo]:not(.bar):click". What you've given me is how I find everything on the right side of the last colon which names the event that I'm looking for (click, onItemRollOver, onFocus , etc). But how do I know the syntax and structure of everything to the left of that last : where I'm writing a sort-of-CSS-dojo-style selector to filter out the.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure you want to know that level of detail from the widget you register events for. Does the widget not offer you a CSS-agnostic way of registering a click (or other) event with the widget you're interested in? E.g. `widget.on("myEvent", function (e) { ... });`.